# Perl : my variable is not consider in my string

Tags: perl

In gedit, pink is the color for strings, green for variables.

As you can see in this image, when I try to add a password in my echo, my variable `$log` is in pink, so Perl considers it to be a string.

How can I change this? I need Perl to consider `$log` to be a variable

[image: code]

I do not have error, but the code does not add the password to my accounts

Here is the code as text

```
open( LIST, "<liste-utilisateur.txt" ) or die "ERREUR FICHIER";

while ( <LIST> ) {

    if ( $_ =~ /^([A-Za-zéè\s-]*);([A-Za-zéè\s-]*);([A-Za-z\s-]*);([A-Za-z\s-]*);([A-Za-z\s-]*)$/ ) {

        #$1=>Nom
        #$2=>Prenom
        #$3=>Login
        #$4=>groupe

        print $1;
        print $2;
        my $log = "loc" . uc $3;
        print "$log";

        #my $newgroup = `$groupadd -f $4`;
        #my $newuser = `$useradd $log -g users -G $4 -c '$2.$1'`;

        my $password = `echo -e "'$5'\n'$5'" | passwd --stdin $log`;

        close( LIST );
```

Comment: Backticks interpolate as double-quoted strings (i.e. `\`...\`` is the same as `readpipe(qq\`...\`)`), so that's not a problem. (You do suffer from shell command injection bugs, though. Use String::ShellQuote's `shell_quote`)

Comment: If $log has white space in it, that would be an issue

Comment: Tip: Probably should use `chomp; my @fields = split /;/;` instead of `if ( $_ =~ /^([A-Za-zéè\s-]*);([A-Za-zéè\s-]*);([A-Za-z\s-]*);([A-Za-z\s-]*);([A-Za-z\s-]*)$/ )`.

Comment: You are inserting arbitrary text into code without first converting the arbitrary text into code first (e.g. using aforementioned `shell_quote`).

Comment: `my $cmd = shell_quote('printf', "%s", "$5\n$5\n") . " | " . shell_quote('passwd', '--stdin', $log);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with what you have written, not with its colour! If you use a different editor to look at the same source files then you are very likely to see different colours, or everything may be in the same colour

The way your editor colours the code is just for your convenience. The Perl compiler will see and process only the text

Syntax colouring can often alert you to errors like unterminated string or comments that can swallow the rest of the program, or perhaps to a missing closing parenthesis. But because Perl is very difficult to parse, Perl syntax colouring is often not very good. As you can see, *gedit* has misunderstood the line

```
my $password = `echo -e "'$l5'\n'$5'" | passwd --stdin $log`;
```

colouring `` `echo -e "' ``
and `` '" | passwd --stdin $log` ``
in pink because it

naïvely believes that the opening backtick `` ` `` is closed by the following single quote `'`

It can be very difficult to get quoting right when you are passing a string to the shell for execution. It is much easier to install the
[`String::ShellQuote`](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote)
module and let it take care of any corner cases